# C++ Game Programming. Error: expected ')' before ':' token

Tags: c++

I'm going through the tutorial on [Lazyfoo](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php): 'Beginning Game Programming'. I've just completed tutorial number 4.

My problem is as follows:

The code works fine apart from the line:

```
SDL_Surface* loadSurface( std::string path );
```

The error reads:

> error: expected ')' before ':' token

I've come to the conclusion that the error might have something to do with the headers. It's possible I should add something to the `SDL.h` header.

I also added the `stdbool.h` header to fix a separate problem. I wonder if that has caused issues.

Here's the full code, which is just the tutorial code (EDIT: **I've put the problematic line in bold**)
(or at least those stars have gone around it. Doesn't appear to be bolding within the code. It's near the beginning, line 33):

```
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//Key press surfaces constants
enum KeyPressSurfaces
{
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL
};

//Starts up SDL and creates window
bool init();

//Loads media
bool loadMedia();

//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

//Loads individual image
**SDL_Surface* loadSurface( std::string path );**

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

//The images that correspond to a keypress
SDL_Surface* gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL ];

//Current displayed image
SDL_Surface* gCurrentSurface = NULL;

bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( gWindow == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
            }
        }

        return success;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
    //Loading success flag
    bool success = true;

    //Load default surface
    gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT ] = loadSurface( "04_key_presses/press.bmp" );
    if( gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT ] == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load default image!\n" );
        success = false;
    }

    //Load up surface
    gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP ] = loadSurface( "04_key_presses/up.bmp" );
    if( gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP ] == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load up image!\n" );
        success = false;
    }

    //Load down surface
    gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN ] = loadSurface( "04_key_presses/down.bmp" );
    if( gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN ] == NULL )
    {
        printf( "failed to load down image!\n" );
        success = false;
    }

    //Load left surface
    gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT ] = loadSurface( "04_key_presses/left.bmp" );
    if( gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT ] == NULL )
    {
        printf( "failed to load left image!\n" );
        success = false;
    }

    //Load right surface
    gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT ] = loadSurface( "04_key_presses/right.bmp" );
    if( gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT ] == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load left image!\n" );
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

void close()
{
    int i;
    //Deallocate surface
    for( i < KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL; ++i; )
    {
    SDL_FreeSurface( gKeyPressSurfaces[ i ] );
    gKeyPressSurfaces[ i ] = NULL;
    }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}

SDL_Surface* loadSurface( std::string path )
{
    //Load image at specified path
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = SDL_LoadBMP( path.c_str() );
    if( loadedSurface == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError() );
    }

    return loadedSurface;
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

    //Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        //Load media
        if( !loadMedia() )
        {
            printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            //Main loop flag
            bool quit = false;

            //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;

            //Set default current surface
            gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT ];

            //While application is running
            while( !quit )
            {
                //Handle events on queue
                while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                    {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                    //User presses a key
                    else if( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
                    {
                        //Select surfaces based on key press
                        switch( e.key.keysym.sym )
                        {
                        case SDLK_UP:
                        gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP ];
                        break;

                        case SDLK_DOWN:
                        gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN ];
                        break;

                        case SDLK_LEFT:
                        gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT ];
                        break;

                        case SDLK_RIGHT:
                        gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT ];
                        break;

                        default:
                        gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT ];
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                    }

                //Apply the current image
                SDL_BlitSurface( gCurrentSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

                //Update the surface
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
                    }

                }
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The compiler will have told you which line the error occurred on. Could you highlight it for us.#

Comment: Add `#include <string>` to your list of includes

Comment: `<string.h>` and `<string>` are not the same.  `std::string` resides in `<string>`.

Comment: Yeah, as @RichardCritten said, you included `string.h` which is for compatibility with c functions like `strlen`. `#include <string>` is for `std::string`

Comment: In `close` you don't initialize `i` to a value but use it in a `for` loop. This is going to cause you problems.!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I will fix this.

Comment: It would help future readers if you state which compiler you are using (because every compiler words the errors differently).

Comment: Good point. I am using Codeblocks. This was my first post, so I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. If you're on windows, I think it uses MinGW32 as default. Please check.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Yes, I'm using MinGW32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointer out, you should try including C++'s string.

```
#include <string>
```

However, if that's your problem, the compiler should have said `string` is not in the `std` namespace.

---

To me it looks like the compiler doesn't know about the `::` namespace operator.

The possible cause is that you're using a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler.

C doesn't have a notion of namespace, and it has no `std::string`.

---

Make sure your source file's extension is a C++ one (like `.cpp`) as opposed to C (`.c`).

Depending on your compiler, you might need to tell it you mean C++ and not C.
If you're using *gcc*, try *g++* instead.

Comment: This appears to have fixed it, thank you :)

I was using the wrong header. I should have included <string>, and for some reason the whole file was .c rather than .cpp.

Thanks everyone for the help and other issues pointed out :)

Comment: What did? To include `std::string`?

Comment: std::string is contained in <string>, but this was part of a larger problem. You were right in that the compiler didn't know about the :: namespace operator. Fixed the file format and changed the header.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
#include <string>
```

instead of:

```
#include <string.h>
```